# subprocess, Popen to run command in a module

Tags: python, subprocess

i want to call a binary program from within my module. i am having problem with subprocess finding the binary.

so  i have

```
myModule/
-classWrappingBinary.py
-binary_file.out
```

and in classWrappingBinary.py i have somthing like

```
sbp.Popen(['./binary_file.out']
```

which doesnt work. so how can i successfully call the Popen command? i am going to use it by importing the module like,

```
import myModule
a = myModule.classWrappingBinary.MyClass()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the variable `__file__` and extract the directory information from it.  The most reliable way is

```
name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) or  ".", "binary_file.out")
subprocess.Popen(name)
```